# Convert dataframe into dictionary and iterate over its key-value pair

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a dictionary based on the `insulation_table` dataframe, where the `chrom` column is the key and `start` column is the value.
For each value, I want to perform downstream analysis, where `end = start+ 90*windows[0]`.

My code has been running for a long time and I'm not sure whether its due to an error.

```
import pandas as pd
import cooler
import cooltools.lib.plotting
from cooltools import insulation
import cooltools


# Calculating genome-wide contact insulation
windows = [3*int(j), 5*int(j), 10*int(j), 25*int(j)]
insulation_table = insulation(clr, windows, verbose=True, clr_weight_name="weight",ignore_diags=2)
first_window_summary =insulation_table.columns[[ str(windows[-1]) in i for i in insulation_table.columns]]
    
# Dictionary containing chromosome name and start value
start_dict = dict(zip(insulation_table.chrom, insulation_table.start))
for key, value in start_dict.items():
    start = value
    end = start + 90*windows[0]
    region = (key, start, end)
```

Data:

`clr.chromnames`

```
['chrM',
 'chr1',
 'chr2']
```

`windows`

```
[600, 1000, 2000, 5000]
[1500, 2500, 5000, 12500]
[3000, 5000, 10000, 25000]
[6000, 10000, 20000, 50000]
[15000, 25000, 50000, 125000]
[30000, 50000, 100000, 250000]
[60000, 100000, 200000, 500000]
[150000, 250000, 500000, 1250000]
[300000, 500000, 1000000, 2500000]
[750000, 1250000, 2500000, 6250000]
[1500000, 2500000, 5000000, 12500000]
[3000000, 5000000, 10000000, 25000000]
[600, 1000, 2000, 5000]
[1500, 2500, 5000, 12500]
[3000, 5000, 10000, 25000]
[6000, 10000, 20000, 50000]
[15000, 25000, 50000, 125000]
[30000, 50000, 100000, 250000]
[60000, 100000, 200000, 500000]
[150000, 250000, 500000, 1250000]
[300000, 500000, 1000000, 2500000]
[750000, 1250000, 2500000, 6250000]
[1500000, 2500000, 5000000, 12500000]
[3000000, 5000000, 10000000, 25000000]
[600, 1000, 2000, 5000]
[1500, 2500, 5000, 12500]
[3000, 5000, 10000, 25000]
[6000, 10000, 20000, 50000]
[15000, 25000, 50000, 125000]
[30000, 50000, 100000, 250000]
[60000, 100000, 200000, 500000]
[150000, 250000, 500000, 1250000]
[300000, 500000, 1000000, 2500000]
[750000, 1250000, 2500000, 6250000]
[1500000, 2500000, 5000000, 12500000]
[3000000, 5000000, 10000000, 25000000]
```

`resolution`

```
['200',
 '500',
 '1000']
```

Comment: OK, and what have you done?  Did it work?